# KryoException: Class kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization

Tags: corda

I'm using M13 (will move to M14 asap). Seeing this exception:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
```

immediately preceeded by:

```
E 15:11:10 [rpc-observation-sender-0] messaging.ObservableContext.sendMessage - Failed to send message, kicking client. Message was Observation(id=ObservableId(toLong=8088750694041100169), content=[rx.Notification@9edc8e12 OnError null])
```

When attempting to invoke my own flow from a client RPC.I have checkedd that custom data types have the @CordaSerializable attribute.

I've seen an answer to another question which indicates there is  bug in M13 in connection with RPC serialisation. Could this explain the above exception?

Am really stuck on this, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Full stack trace:

```
E 15:11:10 [rpc-observation-sender-0] messaging.ObservableContext.sendMessage - Failed to send message, kicking client. Message was Observation(id=ObservableId(toLong=8088750694041100169), content=[rx.Notification@9edc8e12 OnError null])
 com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization
Serialization trace:
throwable (rx.Notification)
at net.corda.core.serialization.CordaClassResolver.checkClass(CordaClassResolver.kt:65) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.CordaClassResolver.getRegistration(CordaClassResolver.kt:35) ~[main/:?]
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.getRegistration(Kryo.java:488) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCKryo.getRegistration(RPCStructures.kt:74) ~[main/:?]
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.writeClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:97) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClass(Kryo.java:540) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:76) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.write(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:66) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:651) ~[kryo-4.0.0.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt.serialize(Kryo.kt:169) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt$serialize$1.execute(Kryo.kt:151) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt$serialize$1.execute(Kryo.kt) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoPoolWithContext.run(Kryo.kt:652) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt.serialize(Kryo.kt:151) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.core.serialization.KryoKt.serialize$default(Kryo.kt:150) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Observation.writeToClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:170) ~[main/:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.ObservableContext.sendMessage(RPCServer.kt:411) [main/:?]
at net.corda.node.services.messaging.RpcServerObservableSerializer$write$observableWithSubscription$1$onNext$1.run(RPCServer.kt:446) [main/:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
E 15:54:42 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - RPC reply arrived to unknown RPC ID RpcRequestId(toLong=8669965257690653719), this indicates an internal RPC error.
E 15:54:42 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - RPC reply arrived to unknown RPC ID RpcRequestId(toLong=6979460553466678543), this indicates an internal RPC error.
E 15:54:42 [Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)] internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - RPC reply arrived to unknown RPC ID RpcRequestId(toLong=2006512959418997107), this indicates an internal RPC error.
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the stacktrace?

Comment: Done - thanks for your looking at this.

Comment: Thanks. Often there's a second stack trace - one for what's actually gone wrong in the flow to cause a NullPointerException, and then this second one when Kryo tries to serialise the NullPointerException. Can you see if there's a second set of error messages related to the activity of the flow?

Comment: That's interesting to learn. I stepped through FlowStateMachineImpl::run() and noticed a Throwable exception (not FlowException) was being thrown. Traced it back to my code looking for an attachment which wasn't there! Is there something I can do to ensure more meaningful exceptions are shown when an exception is thrown from a flow? (specifically KotlinNullPointerException)

Comment: .... obviously checking for null and throwing a specific exception but what if a flow throws an exception which is neither a flowexception nor one envisaged by the flow dev?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by `KotlinNullPointerException` being thrown in the flow. `KotlinNullPointerException` is not on the RPC client serialisation whitelist, so this error is thrown, rather than the root cause.

We're investigating why `KotlinNullPointerException` is on the RPC client whitelist, but **not** on the node whitelist: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/1268.

Comment: Thanks very much for your attn 